# equivalent react function for window.location.replace()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
if (data.success === true) {
   window.location.replace('/verify')
}
```

For react function based component I've tried `useNavigate` hook. What is the equivalent method for React class based component for loading the new page without reloading the entire window, I feel like it would be preferable to load the page via the react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific equivalent to `useNavigate` in class components, but one alternative is that you can wrap your functional component in a class component:  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/#using-with-class-component

`Window.open()` might suit your needs too.